# correct usage of "Ask of"?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I know how to use "ask of" in many cases. But I have encountered a sentence, that for me it is wrong. But, since i am not a native English speaker I can not be sure.

> Implement an application allowing parents to ask questions **of** school personnel.

What this sentence "means", is that, an application will be implemented that will allow parents ask questions **to** school personnel, for example about how to help their children with homework and such.

I didn't write it, a native English speaker did, and he said it is a nuance of English, related with "ask of".
But when I read it, I feel it means that the parents will be able to ask questions **about** school personnel.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me if this is the correct usage and why.

Comment: BTW, "Implement ... personnel" is what I call stilted or self-important business speak. If it were a really good (but bad) example, they'd have written "Implement an Application ... to ask questions of School Personnel." using incorrect capitalization to Emphasize  Importance. People get into a bad habit of doing this because they don't trust the language itself, and perhaps half-conscously don't trust in their own abilities to use it correctly. They falsely hype words or structures, without realizing that simple and direct is more powerful. (continued ...)

Comment: (... continued)  "Create an application allowing parents to ask school personnel questions." OOPS notice even that simpler version is not a full sentence! Another Biz Speak problem... well, ok, maybe it was a bullet point in a list of todo items ... "We should create an application allowing parents to ask school personnel questions online." Though longer, I think it is clearer and more direct.

Comment: @HowardPautz you are completely right! This is a business text. And it is also part of a list of bullets :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "correct" preposition is just a matter of idiomatic usage...

We ***ask*** a question **of** someone we hope may answer it.

We ***put*** or ***pose*** a question **to** that person.

We also sometimes [**direct** a question **at**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I%20love%20a%20man%20in%20uniform%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22directed%20a%20question%20at%22&tbm=bks) someone, but that wouldn't really work in OP's context. It's far less common overall, and tends to be used in respect of a *single* question (or single series of questions).

---

It's worth pointing out that all the above variants involving prepositions are relatively uncommon compared to the simple version - normally, we just ***ask someone*** a question.

Comment: There's also a style aspect. All three (of/to/at) are third-party like. For instance, I'd not say "I would like to ask a question of FumbleFingers" directly here :)) Nor, "I would like to pose a question to FumbleFingers" - unless of course, I wanted to point *at* F.F. and make an example of his writing in a stilted sort of way.  This is what polititians do on the debate floor. However, if @Dzyann noticed that I had asked F.F. something, Dzyann might post elsewhere "Howard posed this silly question to FumbleFingers."  "Ask not of your country what it can do for you..."

Comment: @Howard: Not sure what you mean by "third-party like". It's true that we're more likely to say *"He asked **me** a question"*, rather than *"He asked a question **of me**"* - but that would be the same if he were asking ***John***, for example. It's just that with a longer noun phrase and/or more formal context it might seem a bit clumsy to rely on position and forget the preposition.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I couldn't find a term for the concept and obviously didn't spell it out clearly. I mean that weird sort of "objectification" and indirection that the three examples (of/to/at) cause. Between people who are "present" with each other actually or virtually, using those forms intentionally are implicit ad hominem.  So pointing this comment at you, I ask of you, does this clarify my position (Sir)?   :)) Me doth think we're going full-tilt retro here :-P

Comment: btw +1 for the excellent answer to the OP. Would be enlightening to determine how many questions here and on ELU are based on *prepositions*!

Comment: @HowardPautz I like how you write! FumbleFingers When you say you "ask of someone", are you implying that you expect them to answer? What I mean is, would you understand from my sentence that the school teachers ought to answer the questions? Or would you understand is more like an option, if they want, they will answer.

Comment: @Dzyann You can't predict the future, but I think it's implied that if a school is setting up a system for parents to ask teachers questions, the teachers are going to be expected to answer. That said, this doesn't apply to "ask of someone" in *all* cases; just in the specific case presented in this question. You certainly *hope* for an answer (why else would you ask the question? Unless of course it's rhetorical) but you can't be sure you'll get one, no. +1 to the answer :)

Comment: @Dzyann: Note that you can also [ask of someone that they **do** something](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22ask+of+him+that+he%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) (carry out some action, as opposed to simply answering a question). There's also Howard's implied point that *asking questions **of** someone* tends to sound dated/formal, and the mere fact that ***of*** suggests *getting something ***from** someone*. In a roundabout way, all those points imply greater expectation of a response if "of" is included - but that's a very subtle point, not normally likely to be relevant.

Comment: @WendiKidd thx for that - I was struggling a bit how to say what you said :-O @ Dsyann as FumbleFingers points out, this is subtle but would fly under the radar of most readers. As always, the *best* thing any writer can do is write simple, clear, and direct. (Unless, of course, it makes your boss's boss mad and gets you all fired :) I love English and languages in general, but I haven't fallen on my sword for them - although Bad BizNess EngFish sure looks more painful than a sword's tip ...

Comment: @Howard: The likes of you and I may get a kick out of dissecting the subtleties of English, but I think that might be a bit intimidating for the average *learner*. I think I'd better edit my answer to point out that the most common format, which works fine in most contexts, doesn't use a preposition at all (and is thus more reassuringly simple to learn! :).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand and certainly agree with your concern - we have to practice what we preach :)) But I'd still leave your answer stand - or just add to it, because it IS a good answer.  (Ahh, the separation of ELL and ELU, eh ?)

Comment: @Howard: I'm surprised you're not more active on ELU (Yeah, yeah - I know I've got too much time on my hands! :) Personally, I find being active on *both* sites makes me more aware of the different perspectives questioners are usually looking for. I certainly find it more challenging to try and put myself in the shoes of someone who usually doesn't want to be "talked down to", but doesn't necessarily want to know every last detail which could in the end simply become even more confusing than what might have started off as "blissful ignorance".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thanks. I started here because I used to tutor English in Germany, and kind of understand the struggle to learn another language - English IS hard.  Am just plumbing the depths of ELU now. It's still weird to me because the last several days of posts on ELU seem to be more ELL-like (granted ELL is beta). On meta.ELU, I posted about ELL vs ELU and got a downvote within 2 mins. That let me know I was a bit off. (Hey. Wait a second - that wasn't *you*, was it ? ;-P )  ELU looks good for depth. Thinking of readers of either: keep it simple here and complex there ?

Comment: @Howard: I certainly don't *remember* downvoting [your meta answer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/779/126). It has no up *or* downvotes right now, so if you definitely recall seeing a downvote, *somebody* must have reversed their vote. I doubt that was me, but I wouldn't want to stake my life on it. After all, you did explicitly say you disagreed with the mere fact of me asking the question in the first place (plus there's an off-putting typo in your final sentence). But I will admit I thought Wendikidd's extended and informative comment was somewhat better than the answer itself!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments! I actually like to understand the subtleties. Not every write actually uses them, but some do. So I find it very useful to understand them. And I could not get my head around this use of the preposition "of". For me "ask a question of someone" feels a bit redundant, because of the meanings of the words. I think adding detail into your answers can only help. First having a simple straight answer and then going into detail, you never know what portion will make the OP do the click. Continues...

Comment: It all depends on how the mechanics of the OP's native language and also on how the OP's think. I certainly like rules to understand the nuances of the language. Or even the absence of them. To understand what is going on or supposed to be going on inside the mind of the person saying helps a lot. Therefore I thank you for answering my comments and explain some of the subtleties